# how to preload and play an encrypted movie in/from the browser cache using only html5 and javascript (w/o flash)

Tags: javascript, html, caching, encryption

I want to preload a HTML5 video in the browser cache but in an encrypted format.
How can I play this video whitout using flash or similar plugins just plain javascript/html5.
How can I decrypt the file from the cache and play it in the browser?
Any sugestions?

Thank you

Comment: how long is the video? (the http cache is not an endlessly deep chasm)

Comment: 10-15 minutes, around 10-30 MB

Comment: ok, that's not too big, i was thinking gigs and gigs... you can just load it in an invisible <video preload src=url> tag and then play() it when needed. <video> recently started supporting some secure playback formats, but not many, and results may vary heavily be browser...